# How to click button based on user input?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

e.g Site: https://www.jdsports.com.sg/product/white-adidas-ultraboost-21-primeblue-womens/16140531_jdsportssg/

```
const size = prompt('Size? ')
page.evaluate(size => {
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('btn btn-default  ')];
const targetElement = elements.find(e => e.innerText.includes(size));
targetElement && targetElement.click();
}, size);
```

Im using puppeteer.
At the moment i am trying to get the automation to click on the size based on the users input. Above is the current code I have but it isn't working.

heres how an product size button html:

```
<button data-e2e="pdp-productDetails-size" type="button" class="btn btn-default  " data-price="SGD 260.00" data-sku="16140531_jdsportssg.2910757" data-upc="4064036981142" data-fulfilment-infopage="" data-pool=" 1 " data-stockcheckeravailable="0" data-stock="1" title="Select Size 4">
            4
    </button>
```

So im trying to click the button based on the text. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way.

```
await page.evaluate(size => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default')).filter(e => {
    return e.innerText == size
  }).forEach(element => {
    if (element) element.click();
  });
}, size);
```

By the way if you are going to use `e.innerText.includes(size)` and someone puts in size 5 into the prompt it will check the selector for anything that contains a size 5.

For example:

There are sizes 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5 And i pick size 5.

`e.innerText.includes('5')` will pick any of them that contains the number 5 so it could even pick the size 4.5.

You could try.

```
await page.evaluate(size => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('#itemOptions .options .btn')];
  const targetElement = elements.find(e => e.innerText == size);
}, size);
```

You could also use.

```
await page.evaluate(size => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#itemOptions .options .btn')).filter(e => e.innerText == size).forEach(e => e.click());
}, size)
```

Comment: how do i go about implementing the bottom 2 code Sorry Im kinda new to puppeteer.

Comment: and coding in gerneral just started a month back haha @entlassungspapi

Answer (score 1):

Class selectors need dots and do not need spaces. Try

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-default')];
```

instead of

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('btn btn-default  ')];
```